# Disconnect from a hub in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am creating a single page web application which uses SignalR to be notified of changes on the server. I am new to SignalR and trying to understand how I can have a client only listen to certain events depending on which view they are on. For instance, if the user is viewing customer information then they want to be notified if this data changes, however if they are not viewing this data then there is no need to be notified about any changes.

I thought I might be able to use hub proxies and unsubscribe or disconnect when I no longer need to know about information from that hub. Below is how I attempted to achieve this:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);

// When I want to receive notifications I subscribe to the event
proxy.on('CustomerChanged', function() { ... });

// When I want to stop receiving notifications
proxy.off('CustomerChanged');
```

This does stop the event handler being called, however looking at fiddler the data is still sent to the browser even though the handler has been turned off.

Is there a way to stop listening for notifications on the client side so that the server will not even send any data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use groups.

In your Hub you can add a user to a group very easily.  Here's an example via the OnConnected method on the hub (this can be done at any time, anywhere):

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "foo");

    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

And you can then remove a user from a group easily.  An example via the OnDisconnected method (this can be done at any time, anywhere):

```
public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
    Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, "foo");

    return base.OnDisconnected();
}
```

Lastly you can send data to all clients subscribed to a group via:

```
Clients.Group("foo").bar();
```

Therefore for your use case, when you want a user or set of users to be notified add them to a group, that way when data is sent to the group they will receive it;  when they should no longer receive data for the specific group, remove them from it.

Hope this helps!